# How to check if all numbers in an object are within a certain range?

Tags: javascript, validation, range

One of the features I'd like to include in my current JS/jQuery project is to allow users to export and import their saved data. The import/export data is just one big object being ran through JSON.stringify and JSON.parse, and implementing a basic version of that has worked well, but I'd like to validate the imported data to make sure it will work(this is less about working as JavaScript and more about working within the rules of the game I'm making).

I'd like to come up with a more efficient script to validate this big complicated object. The only parts of the object I'm concerned with are the numbers, but it also includes strings, arrays, nested objects. Some of the nested objects include numbers I'm concerned with, but also more other junk including even further nested objects. Currently, I'm using jQuery's each() function to loop over each subsection of the object and evaluate it, but this requires me to write an each function for each subsection I'm concerned with.

How can I feed a function this whole object and have it look at just the numbers to see if they're greater than or less than a set value?

Edit: Pasting the object here, the goal is to check if all of the numbers. Some need to be between 0 and 3, some need to be between 0 and 9.

```
{
"meta": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Test",
    "concept": "test description"
},
"coreAttributes": {
    "Strength": 3,
    "Finesse": 1,
    "Perception": 9,
    "Stamina": 1,
    "Agility": 1,
    "Wits": 1,
    "Willpower": 1,
    "Charisma": 1,
    "Intelligence": 1
},
"skills": {
    "Toughness": ["Strength", "STR", 0],
    "Stealth": ["Finesse", "FIN", 0],
    "Alertness": ["Perception", "PER", 3],
    "Investigate": ["Perception", "PER", 0],
    "Athletics": ["Agility", "AGI", 0],
    "Drive": ["Wits", "WIT", 0],
    "Survival": ["Wits", "WIT", 0],
    "Guts": ["Willpower", "WIL", 4],
    "Hardware": ["Intelligence", "INT", 0],
    "Humanities": ["Intelligence", "INT", 0],
    "Medicine": ["Intelligence", "INT", 0],
    "Science": ["Intelligence", "INT", 0],
    "Software": ["Intelligence", "INT", 0],
    "Charm": ["Charisma", "CHA", 0],
    "Manipulate": ["Charisma", "CHA", 0]
},
"unrolledSkills": {
    "Contacts": 0,
    "Languages": 0,
    "Resources": 0
},
"combatSkills": {
    "Unarmed": ["Strength", "STR", 0],
    "Defense": ["Finesse", "FIN", 0],
    "Melee": ["Finesse", "FIN", 0],
    "Firearms": ["Perception", "PER", 0],
    "Ballistics": ["Perception", "PER", 0],
    "Initiative": ["Wits", "WIT", 0]
},
"attacks": {},
"status": {
    "currentEndurance": 4,
    "currentSpeed": 4,
    "currentEntanglement": 4,
    "body": {
        "upper": {
            "wounds": 0,
            "armor": ["", 0]
        },
        "lower": {
            "wounds": 0,
            "armor": ["", 0]
        },
        "main": {
            "wounds": 0,
            "armor": ["", 0]
        },
        "off": {
            "wounds": 0,
            "armor": ["", 0]
        },
        "legs": {
            "wounds": 0,
            "armor": ["", 0]
        }
    }
},
"styles": {
    "classes": {
        "Strength": {
            "core": 0,
            "spec1": 0,
            "spec2": 0,
            "spec3": 0,
            "aux1": {
                "skill": false,
                "name": "",
                "value": 0
            },
            "aux2": {
                "skill": false,
                "name": "",
                "value": 0
            },
            "aux3": {
                "skill": false,
                "name": "",
                "value": 0
            }
        },
        "Finesse": {
            "core": 0,
            "spec1": 0,
            "spec2": 0,
            "spec3": 0,
            "aux1": {
                "skill": false,
                "name": "",
                "value": 0
            },
            "aux2": {
                "skill": false,
                "name": "",
                "value": 0
            },
            "aux3": {
                "skill": false,
                "name": "",
                "value": 0
            }
        },
        "Perception": {
            "core": 0,
            "spec1": 0,
            "spec2": 0,
            "spec3": 0,
            "aux1": {
                "skill": false,
                "name": "",
                "value": 0
            },
            "aux2": {
                "skill": false,
                "name": "",
                "value": 0
            },
            "aux3": {
                "skill": false,
                "name": "",
                "value": 0
            }
        },
        "Stamina": {
            "core": 0,
            "spec1": 0,
            "spec2": 0,
            "spec3": 0,
            "aux1": {
                "skill": false,
                "name": "",
                "value": 0
            },
            "aux2": {
                "skill": false,
                "name": "",
                "value": 0
            },
            "aux3": {
                "skill": false,
                "name": "",
                "value": 0
            }
        },
        "Agility": {
            "core": 0,
            "spec1": 0,
            "spec2": 0,
            "spec3": 0,
            "aux1": {
                "skill": false,
                "name": "",
                "value": 0
            },
            "aux2": {
                "skill": false,
                "name": "",
                "value": 0
            },
            "aux3": {
                "skill": false,
                "name": "",
                "value": 0
            }
        },
        "Wits": {
            "core": 0,
            "spec1": 0,
            "spec2": 0,
            "spec3": 0,
            "aux1": {
                "skill": false,
                "name": "",
                "value": 0
            },
            "aux2": {
                "skill": false,
                "name": "",
                "value": 0
            },
            "aux3": {
                "skill": false,
                "name": "",
                "value": 0
            }
        },
        "Willpower": {
            "core": 0,
            "spec1": 0,
            "spec2": 0,
            "spec3": 0,
            "aux1": {
                "skill": false,
                "name": "",
                "value": 0
            },
            "aux2": {
                "skill": false,
                "name": "",
                "value": 0
            },
            "aux3": {
                "skill": false,
                "name": "",
                "value": 0
            }
        },
        "Charisma": {
            "core": 0,
            "spec1": 0,
            "spec2": 0,
            "spec3": 0,
            "aux1": {
                "skill": false,
                "name": "",
                "value": 0
            },
            "aux2": {
                "skill": false,
                "name": "",
                "value": 0
            },
            "aux3": {
                "skill": false,
                "name": "",
                "value": 0
            }
        },
        "Intelligence": {
            "core": 0,
            "spec1": 0,
            "spec2": 0,
            "spec3": 0,
            "aux1": {
                "skill": false,
                "name": "",
                "value": 0
            },
            "aux2": {
                "skill": false,
                "name": "",
                "value": 0
            },
            "aux3": {
                "skill": false,
                "name": "",
                "value": 0
            }
        }
    },
    "arcane": {
        "restoration": 0,
        "evocation": 0,
        "abjuration": 0,
        "sublimation": 0,
        "paradigm": 0,
        "telepathy": 0,
        "shift": 0,
        "electromagnetism": 0,
        "gravitonertia": 0,
        "chromodynamism": 0,
        "technology": 0
    },
    "extension": {
        "avatar": 0,
        "proxy": 0,
        "permanence": 0
    }
},
"addenda": {}
```

}

Comment: The word you're looking for is recursion.

Comment: The words we are looking for is sample code.

Comment: @Kris You will have to tell us which numbers can be of which range.

Comment: Damn, I really wanted to answer this question, But there just isn't enough specifications to do so.

Comment: How will the procedure know when the range is 0-3 and 0-9? Wouldn't it be better to run several tests?

Comment: Do you want to correct those values automatically to be within a range or should the program exit on first failure and return 0?

Comment: @Qwerty I'll need to manually determine whether it's testing for 0-3 or 0-9. If the values are out of the range it shouldn't correct them, but rather throw an error or return 0 on the first one.

Comment: How do you want to manually determine to test 0-3 or 0-9? You want to make it interactive? Or will you do `func03(obj.arcane)` and `func09(obj.extension)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below uses recursion to search all keys in a multidimensional object for any numbers lower or greater than the supplied numbers.

Simply call the function like `checkObject(myStuff, 30, 60);` passing in your object, your lowest allowed number, and your highest allowed number

```js
var myStuff = { "results": [
 {
        "ACL": {
            "7UeILO5tC4": {
                "count": "45",
                "read": true
            },
            "role:Leads": {
                "count": "12",
                "read": true,
                "write": true
            }
        },
        "createdAt": "2014-12-16T22:04:46.338Z",
        "finishDate": "12%2F16%2F2014",
        "finishTime": "16%3A4%3A44",
        "objectId": "tVldoxxdCB",
        "passFail": "Pass",
        "passingPercentage": "56",
        "passingPoints": "34",
        "questions": "21",
        "quizName": "Name",
        "quizType": "Flights",
        "teamMember": "Jame Fellows",
        "ttlPossiblePoints": "59",
        "updatedAt": "2014-12-16T22:04:46.338Z",
        "userName": "Jame.Fellows",
        "userPercentage": "95",
        "userPoints": "20",
        "userRightAnswers": "57"
    },

 {
        "ACL": {
            "7UeILO5tC4": {
                "count": "44",
                "read": true
            },
            "role:Leads": {
                "count": "12",
                "read": true,
                "write": true
            }
        },
        "createdAt": "2014-12-16T22:04:46.338Z",
        "finishDate": "12%2F16%2F2014",
        "finishTime": "16%3A4%3A44",
        "objectId": "tVldoxxdCB",
        "passFail": "Pass",
        "passingPercentage": "90",
        "passingPoints": "87",
        "questions": "21",
        "quizName": "Name",
        "quizType": "Flights",
        "teamMember": "Jame Fellows",
        "ttlPossiblePoints": "79",
        "updatedAt": "2014-12-16T22:04:46.338Z",
        "userName": "Jame.Fellows",
        "userPercentage": "76",
        "userPoints": "20",
        "userRightAnswers": "45"
    },
 {
        "ACL": {
            "7UeILO5tC4": {
                "count": "45",
                "read": true
            },
            "role:Leads": {
                "count": "12",
                "read": true,
                "write": true
            }
        },
        "createdAt": "2014-12-16T22:04:46.338Z",
        "finishDate": "12%2F16%2F2014",
        "finishTime": "16%3A4%3A44",
        "objectId": "tVldoxxdCB",
        "passFail": "Pass",
        "passingPercentage": "90",
        "passingPoints": "19",
        "questions": "21",
        "quizName": "Name",
        "quizType": "Flights",
        "teamMember": "Jame Fellows",
        "ttlPossiblePoints": "21",
        "updatedAt": "2014-12-16T22:04:46.338Z",
        "userName": "Jame.Fellows",
        "userPercentage": "95",
        "userPoints": "20",
        "userRightAnswers": "20"
    }
] };

  
// track how many invalid numbers we find
var hasInvalidData=0;


// call our checkObject() function, pass it
// your object, your lowest allowed number, your highest allowed number
checkObject(myStuff, 30, 60);

if(hasInvalidData > 0){
  alert(hasInvalidData + ' invalid numbers were found')
}

function checkObject(object, low, high){
  
    // loop through each property of the object
    for (var property in object) {
      
        // make sure it's a real property and not inherited
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
             
             //get the value of the current property
             var value = object[property];
             
             // if this propery is itself an object, 
             // call this function recursively  
             if(typeof object[property] == "object" && typeof object[property] !== null){
               checkObject(object[property], low, high)
             }
             else{
                // if it's not an object 
                // check if it a a number and not true or false 
                // which wihich isNaN sees as 1 and 0
                if( !isNaN(value) && typeof value != "boolean"){
                   console.log(value);
                   if(value < low){
                     console.log('^ this value is too small ^');
                     hasInvalidData++;
                   }
                   if(value > high){
                     console.log('^ this value is too large ^');
                     hasInvalidData++;
                   }
                }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this solution, I'll probably use something along these lines. This should allow me to test for the couple of different ranges I need to test for.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is actually very simple – recursion.
The below code checks if all numbers are larger than or equal to 2 and will return false on first non-matching number.

```
var x = {
    b: 5,
    c: {
        d: 3,
        e: [1, 2, 3],
        f: function() {}
    },
    g: function() {}
};

var recurse = function(a) {
    var s = true;
    for (prop in a) {
        switch (typeof a[prop]) {
            case "number":
                //Check for conditions here
                console.log("found number " + a[prop]);
                if (a[prop] < 2) {
                    return false;
                }
                break;
            case "object":
                if (a[prop] !== null) {
                    s = s && recurse(a[prop]);
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    return s;
}

recurse(x);
```

Comment: Your code doesn't properly handle `null` values since `null`'s typeof is object.

Comment: @plalx Thank you for your comment, added a condition.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an iterative solution:

```js
var x = {
    b: 5,
    c: {
        d: 3,
        e: [1, 2, 3],
        f: function() {}
    },
    g: function() {}
};

function check (obj) {
    var queue = [obj];
    while (queue.length > 0) {
        var current = queue.shift();
        for (var prop in current) {
            if (!current.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;
            switch (typeof(current[prop])) {
                case "number":
                    // check for conditions here
                    if (current[prop] < 2) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    break;
                case "object":
                    if (current[prop] !== null) {
                        queue.push(current[prop]);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

alert(check(x));
```

It's a bit faster since it can finish early

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, you only need this: *(it also has some fancy visualisation :P)*

```
function traverse(obj, callback, level) {
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        callback.apply(this, [i, obj[i], level||""]);  
        (obj[i] !== null && typeof(obj[i])=="object") && traverse(obj[i],callback,(level||"")+" ");
    }
}

// it is called like this
traverse(obj, valueCheck); 

//obj  -  is your object as in your question
//valueCheck(key, val, level)  -  is your own function to check the value
```

An exemplary `valueCheck()` function might be as follows

```
function valueCheck(key, val, level) {
    // proceed to check only if the value is a number
    if (!isNaN(parseFloat(val)) && isFinite(val)) { 
        var isError = ! ((0 <= val) && (val <= 9));
        console.log(level + key + " : " + val + (isError && " ----------------------- VALUE ERROR" || ""));
    } else {
        // if it's a new object, print shiny "-" at the begining
        (typeof val == "object") && console.log(Array(1+level.length).join("-") + key);
    }
}
```